# Error while converting date to user friendly format

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have date in the following format and my intention is to convert it to a more user friendly format (eg: 5 minutes ago).

```
2017-05-07 18:23:56
```

For this I have the following code. Everything works fine but when the record is new I get an error. I tried modifying the code but only hit a brick wall. Can someone please help me?

```
var DURATION_IN_SECONDS = {
epochs: ['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'minute'],
year: 31536000,
month: 2592000,
day: 86400,
hour: 3600,
minute: 60
};

function getDuration(seconds) {
  var epoch, interval;
 for (var i = 0; i < DURATION_IN_SECONDS.epochs.length; i++) {
epoch = DURATION_IN_SECONDS.epochs[i];
interval = Math.floor(seconds / DURATION_IN_SECONDS[epoch]);
if (interval >= 1) {
  return {
    interval: interval,
    epoch: epoch
  };
}
}
};

function timeSince(date) {
 var seconds = Math.floor((new Date() - new Date(date)) / 1000);
 var duration = getDuration(seconds);
 var suffix = (duration.interval > 1 || duration.interval === 0) ? 's' : '';
 return duration.interval + ' ' + duration.epoch + suffix;
 };
```

P.S. I want to get time in 1 minute ago format and if the interval is too low then I want to see Just now.

Comment: so basically you need currentTime - givenTime = answerInMinutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You doesn't return anything from getDuration() if interval for all epoch is less than 1.

Try next code:

```
function getDuration(seconds) {
    var epoch, interval;

    for (var i = 0; i < DURATION_IN_SECONDS.epochs.length; i++) {
        epoch = DURATION_IN_SECONDS.epochs[i];
        interval = Math.floor(seconds / DURATION_IN_SECONDS[epoch]);
        if (interval >= 1) {
            return {
                interval: interval,
                epoch: epoch
            }
        }
    }

    return {
        interval: '',
        epoch: 'Just now'
    }
};
```

Comment: I tried and If I do that, everything else changes to Just now.

Comment: @Krish, are you sure it was placed in correct place? I've updated code, check it.

Comment: Yes, that was my mistake. Everything works fine now. Thank you very much.